# Use `use-package-always-ensure` inside a function

Tags: use-package

The following init file does not work if `flycheck` is not installed:

```el
(defun install-my-packs ()
 
  (add-to-list 'package-archives  '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
 
  ;; Install use-package
  (unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (package-install 'use-package))
 
  ;; Config
  ;; https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/
  (require 'use-package-ensure)
  (setq use-package-always-pin "melpa"
        use-package-always-ensure t
        use-package-compute-statistics t
        use-package-verbose t
        use-package-always-defer t)
 
  (use-package flycheck)
  ;; More use-package calls ...
  )
 
(install-my-packs)
```

The `use-package-always-ensure` default is not effective and I get the error:

```
Error (use-package): Cannot load flycheck
```

However, if I don't use the function wrapper `install-my-packs`, but I call straight the code in the body of this function, then `use-package` downloads `flycheck` from MELPA.
The init file works, too, if I use `(install-my-packs)` but I individually set `(use-package flycheck :ensure t)` for each package to install.

For obvious reasons, I find convenient to put all the code to initialise my packages in a dedicated function. How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 1):

`use-package` is a macro, so those settings you are `setq`ing will need to have already been evaluated before your macro call is expanded.  This is byte-compilation time if you're compiling the code, or load time for uncompiled code if eager macro expansion is happening.

I expect your immediate problem is arising from eager macro expansion, and that the solution will be to set those values at the top-level, outside of the function which contains the macro call.

As it is the expansion is happening *without* those settings in effect, as the settings aren't made until the function is *called*, but the macro is expanded while that function is being *defined*.

Try this:

```el
(add-to-list 'package-archives  '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

;; Install use-package
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

;; Config
;; https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/
(require 'use-package-ensure)
(setq use-package-always-pin  "melpa"
      use-package-always-ensure t
      use-package-compute-statistics t
      use-package-verbose t
      use-package-always-defer t)

(defun install-my-packs ()
  (use-package flycheck)
  ;; More use-package calls ...
  )

(install-my-packs)
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to better control when a macro expansion should happen? Does `thunk-delay`work for macros?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  I'm a *little* surprised that `use-package` isn't expanding to code which checks those variables at run time (it's somewhat unusual for a macro to have such dynamic dependencies), but I guess in this instance it was deemed to be reasonable.  I suggest that you raise a documentation bug report for this if it's not clear, though.

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17321/how-to-disable-eager-load-time-macro-expansion-in-emacs-24-3 (but outside of debugging I wouldn't recommend doing anything like that).